# How i get the data from text input in kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am new to kivy and kivymd.i want to get the text from text input .but I have facing a problem to call submit function in my python file from button .i used a **navigation drawer code**.
should i have to define the *submit function* in **class ContentNavigationDrawer** or
**class TestNavigationDrawer** ?
Thanks in advance
following is the code

> .py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem, MDList

from kivymd.app import MDApp




class ItemDrawer(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()
    text_color = ListProperty((0, 0, 0, 1))


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()



class TestNavigationDrawer(MDApp):
    namee = ObjectProperty()


    def build(self):
        kv= Builder.load_file("screenmd.kv")
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return kv

    def submit(self):
        print(self.namee.text)




TestNavigationDrawer().run()
```

> .kv

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: "8dp"
    spacing: "8dp"

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "left"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: avatar.height

        Image:
            id: avatar
            size_hint: None, None
            size: "56dp", "56dp"
            source: "data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png"

    MDLabel:
        text: "KivyMD library"
        font_style: "Button"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    MDLabel:
        text: "kivydevelopment@gmail.com"
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    ScrollView:

        MDList:

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 1"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Screen 2"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"


Screen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        background_color: app.theme_cls.primary_dark
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Iota World"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    NavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height

        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager

            Screen:
                name: "scr 1"

                namee:namee


                MDTextField:
                    id:namee
                    hint_text: "Name"
                    helper_text:"forget"
                    pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5 ,'center_y':0.5}
                    size_hint_x : None
                    width: 300
                MDRectangleFlatButton:
                    text: "Submit"
                    pos_hint : {'center_x':0.5 ,'center_y':0.4}
                    text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                    md_bg_color: 1, 1, 0, 1
                    on_release:
                        print("success")
                        app.submit()


            Screen:
                name: "scr 2"

                MDLabel:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    halign: "center"

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer

            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
                id: content_drawer
```

> error

```
print(self.namee.text)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `self.root.ids.namee.text` instead of `self.namee.text` in your print statement.